# Could e-file rejection rule 1040A-030-01 be due to rounding?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, electronic-filing

I got the following message when I tried to file my income tax electronically:

```
Issue      : Business Rule F1040A-030-01 - Form 1040A, Line 40
'WithholdingTaxAmt' must be equal to the sum of the following:
(1) all  'WithholdingAmt' in [OtherWithholdingStatement] attached to Form 1040A,
    Line 40 and
(2) all of the Forms W-2, Line 2 'WithholdingAmt'.  When evaluating this, a tolerance
    of $5.00 is allowed.
Field/Xpath: /efile:Return/efile:ReturnData/efile:IRS1040A/efile:WithholdingTaxAmt
```

Is it a rounding problem?

Comment: Not necessarily a rounding problem though one _might_ occur if someone rounds off the numbers on lots of W-2 forms or other forms.  Maybe the IRS does not want to hassle someone who made a calculation error while adding up the numbers. The _additional_ tax on $5 or less of income (for someone filing a 1040A and not a 1040) would likely not cover the cost to the IRS of going after it.

Comment: Right - this is saying "you are more than $5 off".  How many W2s (and similar) did you attach?

Comment: I submited only one W2 form

Comment: @TonySmith: And does the amount you reported on Form 1040A Line 40 match the amount on Form W-2, box 2, to within $5?  If not, why not?

Comment: of courst it matched.

Comment: If there was only one W-2 and no other withholding ammounts, then either it was some sort of bug in the e-file system (who knows!) or you have a typo somewhere.  Either way no reason to be rude to a perfectly reasonable question by someone trying to help...

Comment: At this stage, is the IRS just checking the return for internal consistency, or checking against *its* list of W-2s

Comment: @User58220 That is a very interesting point. The OP did not say that he _received_ only one W2 -- just that only one W2 was submitted-- , or maybe he _did_ receive only one W2, but changed jobs during 2014 and received a W2 only from the most recent employer; the other W2 was lost in the mail (sent to old address? since job changes sometimes involve a move from one address to another?) but of course the IRS has its own copy of the lost W2 and so the numbers don't add up.

Comment: Or there is some other hard-working soul using the same SSN?